# Probability- What percentage answered ‘Yes’?

Tags: probability

I am not sure how to solve this question

A study contained the following questions:
(i) Do you own a mountain bike?
(ii) Are you a member of a fitness club?
80% of the respondents answered ‘Yes’ to at least one of the questions, and 80% of the respondents answered ‘No’ to at least one of the questions. What percentage answered ‘Yes’ to exactly one of the questions?
I would appreciate any help
thank you,

Comment: Hint: How many percent replied no to both? How many percent replied yes to both? If the answers are not clear, draw a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Lets consider there are exactly 100 people (so 1% equates to 1 person).

The questions them selves are not important all we want to find is how many people

Answered yes to exactly **one** question

Answered yes to **both** questions

Answered yes to **Neither** question

And we are told

$$\text{one} + \text{both} = 80$$

$$\text{one} + \text{neither} = 80$$

We are not told but we must realise

$$\text{one} + \text{both} + \text{neither} = 100$$

It should be trivial to solve from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(YY)+P(NN)+P(YN)+P(NY) = 1 - (1) $$

$$P(YY)+P(NY)+P(YN) = 0.8  - (2)$$

$$P(NN)+P(NY)+P(YN) = 0.8  - (3)$$

Let $$p = P(NY)+P(YN)$$

$$p+P(YY)+P(NN) = 1$$

$$P(YY)+P(NN) = 1-p$$
Adding the second and third eqauations, we get

$$P(YY)+P(NN)+2(P(NY)+P(YN) = 1.6$$

$$1-p +2p = 1.6$$
$$p = 1.6-1 = 0.6$$